# Переопределить вывод jsona Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Есть сериализатор, мне нужно изменить вывод JSONa

```
class NewsListSerializer (serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """Список новостей"""

    class Meta:
        model = News
        fields = ('id', 'title', 'body_text_preview','image', 'created_at')

    def to_representation(self, obj):
        return {
            'id': obj.id,
            'title': obj.title,
            'body_text_preview': obj.body_text_preview,
            'image': obj.image,
            "create_at": {
                # вместо "created_at": "2020-07-03 14:01:17"
                # разложить формат дататайма на день месяц год
                "day": self.getDay,
                "month": self.getMonth,
                "year": self.getYear,
            },
        }

    def getDay(self):
        return '03'

    def getMonth(self):
        return '07'

    def getYear(self):
        return '2020'
```

Ругается на `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte`

Answer (score 0):

Вот так всё работает как надо:

```
def to_representation(self, instance):
    representation = super().to_representation(instance)

    representation['created_at'] = [
                                    {"year": instance.created_at.strftime("%Y"),
                                     "month": instance.created_at.strftime("%m"),
                                     "day": instance.created_at.strftime("%d")}
                                    ]
    return representation
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class NewsListSerializer (serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """Список новостей"""
    created_at = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = News
        fields = ('id', 'title', 'body_text_preview','image', 'created_at')

    def get_created_at(self, instance):
        return {
            "year": instance.created_at.strftime("%Y"),
            "month": instance.created_at.strftime("%m"),
            "day": instance.created_at.strftime("%d")
        }
```